# Multilingual iPhone App with Audio

Tags: iphone, ios, localization

I'm currently developing an ios app with a lot of audio. I want to release versions in different languages but this means having all the audio in every language, which would take up too much space.

Is there a way to release different versions of the app to the different app stores, including only the relevant audio? Can this be done under one app name/id?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the short answer is 'no', but there are work arounds.

Each app id has one binary associated with it, although you can change the app name by localisation.

Audio is a resource, so there is no reason not to download it separately from a web server under your control.  I don't believe there is any restriction on downloading media.

Alternatively, you can store the audio on Apple's servers and call it downloadable content for a freebie in app purchase.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use webservices to get the audio files from the server and get the relevant file from the server so this may help you to achieve only the relevant data in the application.